# What is the use of explicitly calling EvaluatePacket?

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

I noticed that many examples of C code for communicating via MathLink with the Mathematica kernel first pass an EvaluatePacket call to Mathematica, like this:

```
WSPutFunction(lp, "EvaluatePacket", 1);
WSPutFunction(lp, "Plus", 2);
WSPutInteger(lp, 8);
WSPutInteger(lp, 3);
WSEndPacket(lp);

while (WSNextPacket(lp) != RETURNPKT)
    WSNewPacket(lp);

int result;
WSGetInteger(lp, &result);
```

Thus far I have not been able to find out the purpose of the call to EvaluatePacket. Leaving out the statement `WSPutFunction(lp, "EvaluatePacket", 1L);` seems to work fine. Can somebody tell me a bit more about the use of EvaluatePacket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know why it works if no packet is explicitly given, but section 2.3.1 of [the old MathLink tutorial](http://edenwaith.com/development/tutorials/mathlink/ML_Tut.pdf) is a useful read.

It says,

> Everything that you send to the kernel should be wrapped in a packet head.

Then it details the effect of various packet types. For example, both `EvaluatePacket` and `EnterExpressionPacket` should contain an expression, but the former will not run the main loop, while the latter will.

Thus, I would not omit the packet name even if it does appear to work without it.